# use database with conditional statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to execute a script in 2 different servers having different db names but same tables and data. For this,
I tried using the following statement.

```
if (@@servername= 'srvrA')
    begin 
        use dbA
    end
else    
begin 
        use dbB
    end
```

But for srvrB, it says Database dbA does not exist.

Could someone help me achieving this?

Comment: For a question like this I suspect it might be database specific, so probably worth adding a tag for the database engine you're using.

Comment: I just had an experiment and the problem is that the existence of dbA gets checked even if the expression evaluates to false. I thought it was working enclosed in an EXEC statement but upon further checking it wasn't changing the database, it was still using the default. I guess if no good solutions appear you could just create an empty database schema to get around it. Or maybe call the script specifying the database on the command line and remove the USE altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One more options

- Add linked servers [sp_addlinkedserver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190479%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)
- Mapping between a login local instance and remote server [sp_addlinkedsrvlogin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189811%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

Something like:

```
sp_addlinkedserver  
  @server= N'srvrA',
  @srvproduct= N'',
  @provider= N'SQLNCLI',
  @datasrc= N'srvrA';

sp_addlinkedsrvlogin
  @rmtsrvname = 'srvrA' ,
  @useself = 'FALSE' ,
  @locallogin = 'your_local_login' ,
  @rmtuser = 'your_remote_login' ,
  @rmtpassword = 'your_password'
```

And then your script will look like

```
DECLARE @@srvname nvarchar(10) = 'srvrA'

IF (@@servername = @@srvname)
  BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM srvrA.dbA.your_schema.your_table
  END    
ELSE    
  BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM srvrB.dbB.your_schema.your_table
  END
```

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve your goal if you enable SQLCMD mode.  Toggle SQLCMD mode from the Query menu in sql management studio.  Then the following script will work.

```
if (@@servername = 'srvrA')
    begin
        :setvar dbname dbA
        use $(dbname)
    end
else    
    begin
        :setvar dbname dbB
        use $(dbname)
    end
```

Comment: This doesn't work. SQLCMD variables are set before script execution. `dbname` will always be the value of the last `:setvar`